# How to generate nuget package with specific file organization using cpack/cmake?

Tags: cmake, nuget, cpack

I generate two nuget package with cpack and cmake. My problem is to organize files in my package. I would like to put some files in specific folder.

Actually i have in my first package:

```
/_rels
/package
toto.nuspec
toto.dll
```

But i want to have toto.dll in /lib folder :

```
/_rels
/package
/lib/toto.dll
toto.nuspec
```

I tried to use:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/lib")
```

but i want different file organization for other packages.

Do you have an idea to do this for one specific package ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the desired destination in the `install(TARGET...)` command instead. E.g.,

```
install(
    TARGET toto DESTINATION lib
    # Some other args may follow here, like `COMPONENT`...
  )
```